# Different behaviour of Count function on Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-filter

I have a very strange case, in which the behaviour of Count() differs if it is applied to a filtered model by id, or from other filters.
I have these models:

```
class Segment(models.Model):
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Waypoint(models.Model):
    is_visited = models.BooleanField("is visited", default=False)
    segment = models.ForeignKey("Segment", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="waypoints", null=True, default=None)
```

Let say we have two waypoints both not visited yet, both related to the same segment.
I have one of these waypoints in a queryset, call it `wp`. Now if I perform:

```
to_visit_filter = Q(waypoints__is_visited=False)
seg = Segment.objects.filter(waypoints__in=wp, is_completed=False).annotate(
            wp_to_visit=Count('waypoints', filter=to_visit_filter))

print(seg.first().wp_to_visit)   // 1
```

Instead, if I do:

```
to_visit_filter = Q(waypoints__is_visited=False)
segm_id = [w.segment.id for w in wp]
seg = Segment.objects.filter(id__in=segm_id, is_completed=False).annotate(
            wp_to_visit=Count('waypoints', filter=to_visit_filter))

print(seg.first().wp_to_visit)   // 2
```

In both cases `seg.first()` give the same object instance, but the number of waypoint to visit is different. Why?

Answer (score 0):

In your first query you perform filtering on the *waypoints* (`waypoints__in=wp`) and hence have limited the waypoints to that one selected `Waypoint`. This filtering results in a LEFT OUTER JOIN with the `Waypoint` model and a WHERE clause. Next you perform aggregation and group by on waypoints by using `Count` on `waypoints`. This annotation would use the same join made by the previous call to `filter` and hence obviously your count has the result of 1.

Next in your second query instead of filtering on waypoints, you filter on the segments `id` itself, hence there is no filtering on the waypoints and your query gives you the count of 2.